# S3 upload return 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

Uploading to S3 via HTTP PUT request. Here's my request params:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHRUBWYK7YNNWSLQ&
Expires=1376556204&
x-amz-meta-cachecontrol:max-age=315360000&
Signature=y7%2F96eP5OXWsqjRSh81T6WNHe%2FQ%3D
```

This gives me a response `403 SignatureDoesNotMatch`. The reason why is in the response body, it tells me that the string it tried to match was:

```
PUT

image/png
1376556204
x-amz-meta-cachecontrol:max-age:315360000
/test199801672/608ad506f948b52ab130467a7df99381.png
```

Notice there is a colon after **max-age**. I never passed in a colon! I passed in an **=**. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my complete request (minus the body of-course):

```
PUT /608ad506f948b52ab130467a7df99381.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHRUBWYK7YNNWSLQ&Expires=1376556204&x-amz-meta-cachecontrol:max-age=315360000&Signature=y7%2F96eP5OXWsqjRSh81T6WNHe%2FQ%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: test199801672.s3.amazonaws.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 636109
Content-Type: image/png
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Spentit/88 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/2.00)
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't been apple to solve it @WonderingCoder

Comment: sorry, just want to ask if you have been able to make it work the uploading image to s3? Maybe using Form post instead of PUT?

Answer (score 1):

your s3 signature needs to sign off on the same params you're trying to pass to s3 so if you're having signature errors then i would make sure your s3 signature is signing the proper policy.

amazon meta data `cache-control` param is `x-amz-meta-Cache-Control` you have `x-amz-meta-cachecontrol`. but more importantly you need to pass a value of `max-age=315360000`. you need to escape the `=` in the value otherwise it will be parsed as `max-age` -> `315360000` when you want `x-amz-meta-Cache-Control` -> `max-age=315360000`

in your `PUT` request you can see in the query string that you're submitting `x-amz-meta-cachecontrol:max-age` -> `315360000`

Comment: In my case I was applying a set header in put PUT request that was causing the mismatch issue.